# Structuring Complex Relationships in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Say I have two seperate models User and Event in a HABTM environment.

Now I want to extend this to include information about the relation. Things like if the user is planning on attending the event.

In standard ActiveRecord this would be done with a has_many :through relationship, but from what I have been reading it is a bad idea to try and create this kind of relationship in mongoid. What is a good way to approach this problem? (staying with mongo)

Here's an example of what I would expect for this type of functionality:

```
class User
  field :name
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, :through => :user_events
end

class Event
  field :title 
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :users, :through => :user_events
end

class UserEvent
  field :attending?, :type => Boolean
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :events
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  embeds_many :user_events
end

class UserEvent
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :event 
  embedded_in :user

  field :attending?, :type => Boolean
end

class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
end
```

In order to find all events where the user is attending:

```
user = User.where(:name => 'Joe').first
user.user_events.where(:attending? => true)
```

For a complete example see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/919341)

Comment: This is along the same lines as I was thinking too. Then put a wrapper method in User like get_events() to abstract that user.user_events.events query. I was hoping there was a best practice for this type of relationship developed.

Comment: Exactly, you may also want to have a look at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design. The important point there is "Line item detail objects typically are embedded.". Hope that helps.